# How to work with incoming SMS?

Tags: android, sms

My app should work with incoming SMS. It should be similar to adding SMS sender to black list. And this action should be very simple for the user (like 'reporting spam' in gmail app). But looks like I can not add context menu item for incoming SMS since user can use any app for SMS reading. What else can I do?
I am thinking about re-sending (forwarding) sms to another number, catch it as outgoing SMS. But that is not so simple... And, I don't think that I will get sender's number in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you go to all the trouble of resending it?

All you need to do is register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`. In the `onReceive()` of your receiver, you can check the contents of the SMS, and which number it was sent from. You can then launch an Activity (not recommended), or show a notification (recommended) to ask the user whether or not he wants to mark this as spam. If he does mark it as spam, simply call `abortBroadcast()` to prevent the SMS from reaching the inbox of the user.

Comment: I don't want to ask user about each incoming SMS. I would prefer user to read the SMS and then decide if it should be treated as spam or not. Reading of SMS content, trying to understand if this is spam, may help, but not the best option, imho.

Comment: So don't parse the SMS yourself. From `onReceive()`, launch a dialog styled activity that asks the user what to do. Using a broadcast receiver is the *only* way you can get hold of each SMS and show it to the user, unless you also own the SMS app the user uses.